# Yajra Relationship Call to undefined relationship [XXX_id] on model [App\XXX]

Tags: ajax, laravel, yajra-datatable

I get an error like below
Call to undefined relationship [hotel_id] on model [App\Room]

Model file Hotel.php

```
class Hotel extends Model {
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable   = ['hotel_name', 'hotel_area'];
    public function room() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Room', 'hotel_id');
    }
}
```

Model File Room.php

```
class Room extends Model {
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable   = ['hotel_id', 'room_name', 'bonus_sum'];
    public function hotel() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Hotel', 'hotel_id');
    }
}
```

Controller File RoomController.php

```
public function apiRoom() {
        $rooms = Room::with('hotel');
        return Datatables::eloquent($rooms)
            ->addColumn('action', function ($rooms) {
                return '<a onclick="editForm('.$rooms->id.')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Edit"> <i class="fa fa-pencil text-inverse m-r-10"></i> </a>'.
                '<a onclick="deleteData('.$rooms->id.')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Close"> <i class="fa fa-close text-danger"></i> </a>';
            })
            ->escapeColumns()
            ->toJson();
```

Route file web.php

```
Route::get('rooms-list', 'RoomController@list');
Route::resource('room', 'RoomController', [
        'except' => ['create']
    ]);
Route::get('api/room', 'RoomController@apiRoom')->name('api.room');
```

Migrate create_new_room

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('hotel_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('hotel_id')->references('id')->on('hotels')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->string('room_name');
$table->string('bonus_sum');
$table->timestamps();
```

View File

```
$('#room-table').DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax: "{{ route('api.room') }}",
  columns: [
    {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
    {data: 'hotel.hotel_name', name: 'hotel.hotel_name'},
    {data: 'room_name', name: 'room_name'},
    {data: 'bonus_sum', name: 'bonus_sum'},
    {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
  ]
});
```

It's not related to the database. There is probably an error in the ajax file.

Answer (score 0):

Your hasMany has been defined incorrectly in your `Hotel` class.

Per the API documentation [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.html), you need to pass an instance of the `Room` class through.

```
public function room() {
    return $this->hasMany(App\Room::class, 'hotel_id');
    // OR
    return $this->hasMany('App\Room', 'hotel_id');
}
```

Same applies your `Room` class.

```
public function hotel() {
    return $this->belongsTo(App\Hotel::class, 'hotel_id');
    // OR
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Hotel', 'hotel_id');
}
```

-- EDIT --

On the comment, the `belongsTo` function has the definition:
`belongsTo($related, $foreignKey = null, $ownerKey = null, $relation = null)`

For your `hotel()` relationship on the `Room` class to work, you need to pass the related models key as the second parameter. You should write it like this:

```
public function hotel() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Hotel', 'id', 'hotel_id');
}
```

Comment: ok thanks you. I've updated the part you mentioned But the error continues